# Use sprint number in release name in VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to add the sprint number to the name of the release. Currently I'm using date and release number (incremental) as you can see in the following line

`$(date:yyyyMMdd)_$(rev:_r)`

I want to add the sprint number to this variable to have something like

`sprintNumber_$(date:yyyyMMdd)_$(rev:_r)`

How can I get the sprintNumber for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already resolved using the VSTS API and getting the iterations from the query Get Team Iterations and after that invoking that query from a powershell script and then assigning the selected sprint to the Releasename variable.
[Get Team Iterations](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/iterations)